# align text left in the column and in the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got such header on the page
[image]

But I want to align it like this
[image]

How to do that? My html code looks like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#mytab a:last").tab("show")
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .blackie {
                background: black;
                color: white;
            }
            .header {
                font-size: 25px;
            }
            .column {
                text-align: center;
            }
            .line {
                border-right: 1px solid white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row blackie">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img src="eng.png" width="40px" height="40px"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 header">Admin</div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-3">
                <span class="line"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                email
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span class="line"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 column">
                <span class="logout">
                    <a href="#">Log out</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="mytab">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Liabilities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Admin</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
                        <p>Liabilities</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
                        <p>Events</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
                        <p>Reports</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane">
                        <p>Admin</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Am not clear with your need. can you please jsfiddle it

Comment: Erm...If I was able to jsfiddle it I would be done it myself - alinged text `admin` and others..I even used paint to draw required image(second)
Basically I want to align `admin` to the left and other text - `align in the center of column`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/7ky948j3/2/embedded/result/

You have the problem with padding, every col-md class has padding left nad right 15px, the image in the first col is smaller than the width of the col-md-1 class so it pushes the admi further to the right. If you add the image and Admin in the same col-md the problem will be fixed

```
<div class="col-md-3 header">
    <img src="eng.png" width="40px" height="40px" /> Admin
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Pseudo classes which makes your work easy. here your [output](http://jsfiddle.net/wd86m8rg/6/)

use first-child Pseudo class for these need
here the html

```
 <div class="row blackie">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                <img src="eng.png" width="40px" height="40px"/>
            </div>
     <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11"> <!-- cols depends upon ur nees" -->
             <ul class="main-head">
                     <li>
                         <a href="">Admin</a>
                     </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="">Email</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="">logout</a>
                 </li>
         </ul>
             </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
ul.main-head{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
ul.main-head:after{
 clear:both;
    content:" " ;
    display:table;
}

ul.main-head li{
    float:right; //floats every element to right side
    text-align:right;
    list-style:none;
}
ul.main-head li:first-child{
    float:left; //make the first element to float left
}
ul.main-head li a{
    color:#fff;
}
```

and line-heights and left right margins as your need to 'li' of the topbar for better results.